# Select rows specified in inpubox and select specified columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a VBA newbie and I would really appreciate it if someone would help.

I would like to create an Excel VBA makro, which does the following:

1. It shows a box, where I need to type a starting cell number e.g. A5
2. It shows next box where I need to type last cell number e.g. A17
3. Then Excel selects this range from A5 to A17, but also it selects the rows from A5 to A17, but Excel doesn't have to select whole rows, only from column A to column L.

Please help!

Comment: I'm voting to close: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Comment: The previous two comments are correct; SO isn't a place to build your code for you and this question will probably be closed. Before that happens, though, some suggestions to send you on your way: 1/ Go to the VB Editor and add a UserForm to the workbook. This will be used to "show (the) box". 2/ Don't have the users type in the addresses; instead use the RefEdit control on the user form. Google how to use that. 3/ When you use the RefEdit to get the selected range, look into the EntireRow property of a range. When you've had a shot at this, raise a new question if you're still having trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim f As Long, l As Long
    f = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter first row number", Type:=1)
    l = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter last row number", Type:=1)
    Range("A" & f & ":L" & l).Select
End Sub
```